# Eclipse Kepler: Restore File Transfer confirmation dialog

Tags: eclipse, dialog, transfer, eclipse-kepler

Ok, this should be easy, but for some reason I can't figure it out.

I want to restore the file transfer confirmation dialog that appears after a file has been successfully uploaded.

I clicked the "don't show next time" checkbox, but realize I really do need it.

Comment: Which file transfer dialog? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Is this related to Java development? If it is, try Window -> Preferences -> Java and press the "Clear" button in the section "Java dialogs". Other preferences offer the same option.

Comment: I'm using the built-in file transfer utility with connections.  I use Eclipse with Aptana 3 and CFEclipse for web development.